# Is there any way around the length limitation in mount options?

Tags: mount, linux-kernel, memory, overlayfs

Say I create a series of directories in the form "elem_###", where ### are the integers from 001 to 454, like so:

```
$ dirs=$(seq -felem_%03.0f 454 | tr '\n' ' ')
$ mkdir ${dirs}
```

I then use these directories as `lowerdir` to mount a `overlayfs`:

```
$ dirs=${dirs::-1}
$ mkdir mountpoint
# mount overlay -t overlay mountpoint -o lowerdir=${dirs// /:}
# umount mountpoint
```

It works fine. However, if I do:

```
$ mkdir elem_455
# mount overlay -t overlay mountpoint -o lowerdir=${dirs// /:}:elem_455
mount: /home/username/dir/mountpoint: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on overlay, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
$ dmesg | tail
(...)
[ 1541.668221] overlayfs: empty lowerdir
(...)
```

It fails.

So here's what's happening: while in the first try the length of the options string is 4094 characters, in the second the length is 4103. Also, judging by the error, the string is cut at 4095 characters.

Of course,

```
$ getconf PAGE_SIZE
4096
```

So the options string is apparently limited to the memory page size minus one. Is the limitation imposed by the Linux kernel or is it just the `mount` program? Is there any way around that?

Answer (score 2):

One idea is to aggregate part of dirs into middle overlayfs layers.
And then, we can aggregate them into the final mount point.

```
# mount overlay -t overlay dummy1 -o lowerdir=${dirs// /:}
# mount overlay -t overlay dummy2 -o lowerdir=${dirs// /:}
# ...
# mount overlay -t overlay mountpoint -o lowerdir=dummy1:dummy2:...
```